# Input to select item from list

Tags: python, list

I'm making a ranking system, and I was wondering if you could use an input to select an item from a list. And if the input matches any item in the list, you could assign points to it.

Here's what I got so far:

```
teams = list()
scores = list()

#adding a team
if loop=="1":
    team_name = input("Enter a team name: ")
    print ("This team is succesfully added!")
    teams.append(team_name)

#selecting the team by user input
elif loop=="4":
   test = input("Enter a team name: ")
   if test is any in list(teams):
       score_team = int(input("How many points does this team get? "))
       scores.append(score_team)
   else:
       print("Sorry, thats not a valid team name!")
```

I always get the output:

```
Sorry, thats not a valid team name!.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if test is any in list(teams)`. That doesn't do what you think it does. You're checking if `test` is the function `any` and then checking if the result of that expression is in `teams` (which you're converting from a list to a list).

Comment: `if test in teams:` is all you need

Comment: `if test in teams:`

Comment: I thought that if the input is anything that matches an item on that list, it would select that item and continue.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Just `in`, not `is in`.

Comment: @L.Kappa That's exactly what `in` does.

Comment: @L.Kappa TIP for You : learn what **dict** is I see this more useful here than having two lists

Comment: Alright, thanks guys for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Just check if the list contain the team entered by the user using 'in' keyword. so it should work

```
teams = list()
scores = list()

#adding a team
if loop=="1":
    team_name = input("Enter a team name: ")
    print ("This team is succesfully added!")
    teams.append(team_name)

#selecting the team by user input
elif loop=="4":
   test = input("Enter a team name: ")
   if test in list(teams):
       score_team = int(input("How many points does this team get? "))
       scores.append(score_team)
   else:
       print("Sorry, thats not a valid team name!")
```